# Using Streamreader in C# merge multiple lines into a single line

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

I have searched SO but did not find anything that specifically addresses this issue: So here goes -
I have a text file where the paragraphs have lines of text ending with a "return". So it ends up on separate lines - I would like to merge these multiple lines into a single line.
I am using Streamreader in C# ( VS 2010).

> Example:
>
> GE1:1
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> yyyyyyyyyyyyyy.
>
> hhhhhhhhhhhhh.
>
> GE1:2
>
> zzzzzzzzzzz
>
> kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
>
> and so on....

As you can see in above example some paragraphs have 3 lines and some have two.It varies.
There are thousands of these paras in the text file.

Basically I would like to have my variable "templine" contain the following: (which will be used for further processing).

```
var templine = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyy. hhhhhhhhhhhhh."
```

Code:

```
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test.txt"))
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test2.txt"))
        {
            StringBuilder sb    = new StringBuilder ( );


            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                    string templine = sr.ReadLine();  /// further processing code not relevant.
```

UPDATE:
What i need is a way to detect if a paragraph has 3 lines or two.
I  know how to remove the Newline character etc.. just cant work out how to know when the paragraph ends.

Comment: how to differentiate between two paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

To bring all text into a single string

```
var templine = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp.txt").Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

That .Replace is because it looks like you want your new lines to be replaced with spaces.

If you want to break it up into  2 or 3 line paragraphs, you'll need to specify for us what the delimiter is.

Comment: Thanks Matt. But I believe REadAllText will read the entire file - approx 30,000 paragraphs. I need to read in each paragraph and convert to single line.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove new line char from the string like this

```
string replacement = Regex.Replace(templine  , @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

or

```
templine  = templine.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
templine  = templine.Replace("\r", String.Empty);
templine = templine.Replace("\t", String.Empty);
```

to make single line out of multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expressions.

```
Regex parser = new Regex(@"GE\d*\:\d*\r\n(?<lines>(.*?\r\n){2,3})",
    RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

and then just get all you need:

```
string[] paragraphs = parser.Matches.Cast<Match>().Select(T =>
    Regex.Replace(T.Groups["lines"].Value, @"\t|\n|\r", string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

*(Havn't tested yet.)*

Comment: will this operate on the whole file or detect the end of the paragraph on its own ?